# Protractor helper functions, how to await?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, protractor

I have this block of code:

```
    function searchBox(filterName, objectList, filterField) {
        randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * objectList.length);
        element(by.id(filterName)).clear();
        Delay(delay);
        element(by.id(filterName)).click();
        element(by.id(filterName)).sendKeys(objectList[randIndex][filterField]);
        console.log("FilterName: ", filterName);
        console.log("FilterField: ", filterField);
        Delay(delay);
        element.all(by.repeater(filterName)).each(function (item) {
            item.getText().then(function (text) {
                expect(text).toContain(objectList[randIndex][filterField]);
            })
        });
    };

    it('Search for company name in searchbox on My tab', function () {
        var randIndex;
        $('[ng-click="companyCtrl.tabClick(0)"]').click();
        Delay(delay);
        $('[ng-controller="CompanyListController as companyCtrl"]').evaluate("companyCtrl.partnersList").then(function (partnersList) {
            searchBox('companyFilterMy', partnersList, 'name');
            searchBox('companyFilterMy', partnersList, 'city');
            searchBox('companyFilterMy', partnersList, 'statusText');
        });
    });
```

I would like to do something like `await`-ing each call to the `searchBox` function because as of now the next is called right after the one before.

Answer (score 0):

I installed asyncawait with `npm install --save asyncawait` and then at the top of my spec file I required the two functions like so:

```
var async = require('asyncawait/async');
var await = require('asyncawait/await');
```

After that I adjusted the above code to look like this, and it works:

```
    var searchBox = async(function (filterName, objectList, filterField) {
        randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * objectList.length);
        await (element(by.id(filterName)).clear());
        Delay(delay);
        await (element(by.id(filterName)).click());
        await (element(by.id(filterName)).sendKeys(objectList[randIndex][filterField]));
        console.log("FilterName: ", filterName);
        console.log("FilterField: ", filterField);
        Delay(delay * 5);
        await (element.all(by.repeater(filterName)).each(function (item) {
            item.getText().then(function (text) {
                expect(text).toContain(objectList[randIndex][filterField]);
            })
        }));
        console.log("ASUIHGIUADSHGUH");
        return true;
    });

    it('Search for company name in searchbox on My tab', function () {
        var randIndex;
        $('[ng-click="companyCtrl.tabClick(0)"]').click();
        Delay(delay);
        $('[ng-controller="CompanyListController as companyCtrl"]').evaluate("companyCtrl.partnersList").then(async(function (partnersList) {
            await (searchBox('companyFilterMy', partnersList, 'name'));
            await (searchBox('companyFilterMy', partnersList, 'city'));
            await (searchBox('companyFilterMy', partnersList, 'statusText'));
        }));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of node are you on, and are you using typescript?

When you are on node 7.6 or higher you are able to use the async await out of the box and you don't need a library for you to do it, see also [this link](http://node.green/#ES2017-features-async-functions) for the support and [this link](https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/02/node-76-async-await) how to use it.

If you are using TypeScript 2.3 or higher you can also use the `async/await` and use `ts-node` in your `beforeLaunch()` like this

```
beforeLaunch: () => {
    require('ts-node').register();
}
```

To compile the code "on-the-fly" before running tests

Hope it helps